# How can shifted column-name in place of previous column name when column not contains any value

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm printing a report using ireport tools

Consider there is a table Student which having 4 columns:

1. Student-Id
2. Student-First Name
3. Student-Last Name
4. and Student-Age

In My Student Table Student-Last Name column not contain any values.
i want to generate a report in such a way that if any column name not contains any values  then that column name shifted to another column name, in place of previous column name.

```
Student-Id     Student-First Name     Student-Last Name        StudentAge

201                      Vinay                                       24

202                      Kishore                                     26

203                      Komal                                       28
```

So went I display my report,  I want My Student-Age column name come in placed of  Student-Last Name .

Output:

```
Student-Id             Student-First Name                      Student-Age

201                            Vinay                             24

202                            Kishore                           26

203                            Komal                             28
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `select Student-Id, Student-First Name, Student-Age ...`

Comment: how about col names id,first,last,age, ... give your fingers a break

Comment: just make 2 sub reports, and call when ever/what ever required :| not best solution.. but works